# Ubuntu 18.04.3 live usb won't boot after aborted partial install

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

Apologies if this question is redundant but I've only built a desktop with help before and this is my first Linux install...

So the live usb worked great the first time but as I attempted to install Ubuntu it showed some error to do with LVM I believe after asking about overwriting empty space and then the encryption password set up screen. I changed the settings in those screens to try to bypass this but to no avail. Then I aborted the install and tried booting again but got the common error involving \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found and failing to start MokManager.

I tried messing around with the boot settings as per what other threads had mentioned - disabling secure boot, loading the original HP boot keys (seems to be the only recourse in the BIOS of this 6 yr old Pavilion G6 laptop) but again with no success.

Even after re-imaging the live usb with the original ISO file I still get the same error when trying to boot from it (ssd removed). Any ideas short of trying a different data stick?

Thanks,
Tom